Coupled amplifier circuit
When the circuit is simulated as shown in the figure below, the input voltage value (peak to peak voltage=range) without distortion of the output voltage waveform was 80 mV. I wonder why it is distorted when the voltage is higher than that.



I wonder why it is distorted when the voltage is higher than that.

In short: you have too much circuit gain. This is due to the 20 μF capacitor across the emitter resistor in the 2nd stage of the amplifier. In the first amplifier stage the gain is approximately 5. This is simply the ratio of collector resistor to emitter resistor. Yes, it's an approximation but serves its purpose.
In the 2nd stage the emitter impedance at 1 kHz (for example) is dominated by the impedance of the 20 μF capacitor. It has an impedance magnitude of about 8 Ω at 1 kHz hence, the 2nd stage gain is 5000/8 = 625. This is an unfeasibly high voltage gain for this stage and, for other reasons, it might be limited to 100.
But, the overall gain of your circuit will be 500 and, if you have 80 mV p-p at the input, you'd expect to see 40 volt p-p at the output. Given that your total supply rail is 15 volts, the output is heavily distorted and clipped.
I believe that if you examined the output signal more closely you will see that it is clipped when the input is 80 mV p-p. Here's a snapshot from a simulation I did on your 2nd stage using a BC547 transistor with an effective input voltage of 400 mV p-p (as would be produced from the 1st stage amplifier): -

